# Вызов метода одного Activity в другом Activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, activity, мобильные-приложения

У меня есть необходимость при нажатии на кнопку  переходить в контакты и извлекать список контактов с именами, метод который извлекает контакты рабочий. Я данный метод реализовал для первого Activity(layout-экрана), но у меня есть такая же кнопка и на другом экране с таким же функционалом (переходить в контакты и извлекать список). Отсюда вопрос можно ли этот метод вызвать из другого Activity или придется copypaste метод для нового Activity?
P.S. при этом переходить на другой layout не надо
P.s.s ниже представлен сам метод который я хочу вызвать из другого Activity

```
public void getContacts() {
        this.spisokKontaktov=new HashMap<String,String>();
        this.nameNomer=new HashMap<String,String>();
        String phoneNumber = null;
        String nameKontakt="";
        String numberKontakt="";

        //Связываемся с контактными данными и берем с них значения id контакта, имени контакта и его номера:
        Uri CONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
        String _ID = ContactsContract.Contacts._ID;
        String DISPLAY_NAME = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME;
        String HAS_PHONE_NUMBER = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER;

        Uri PhoneCONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
        String Phone_CONTACT_ID = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID;
        String NUMBER = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER;

        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(CONTENT_URI, null,null, null, null);

        //Запускаем цикл обработчик для каждого контакта:
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {

            //Если значение имени и номера контакта больше 0 (то есть они существуют) выбираем
            //их значения в приложение привязываем с соответствующие поля "Имя" и "Номер":
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                String contact_id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex( _ID ));
                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DISPLAY_NAME));
                int hasPhoneNumber = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)));

                //Получаем имя:
                if (hasPhoneNumber > 0) {
                    nameKontakt=name;
                    Cursor phoneCursor = contentResolver.query(PhoneCONTENT_URI, null,
                            Phone_CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[] { contact_id }, null);

                    //и соответствующий ему номер:
                    while (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {
                        phoneNumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(NUMBER));
                        numberKontakt=phoneNumber;
                        this.spisokKontaktov.put(numberKontakt, nameKontakt);
                        this.nameNomer.put(nameKontakt, numberKontakt);
                        Log.i(TAG, "контакт с именем"+nameKontakt+numberKontakt);
                    }
            }
}
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете создать небольшой класс активити с реализацией этого метода (можно переписать его так, чтобы он возвращал не войд, а список контактов в виде HashMap). Затем наследуйте от этого класса классы ваших двух активностей.

Или можете сделать этот метод публичным и статическим (так тоже рекомендую переписать его, чтобы он возвращал не войд, а список контактов в виде HashMap)
В другом активити вызывать его вот так:

```
HashMap<string, string> contacts = YourActivityName.getContacts();
```

Можно создать класс модели Contact, добавить в него необходимые поля, и возвращать массив этих контактов, как описано здесь:
[ответ на английском stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41827064/6824996)